# How to structure elements in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So I'm using jQuery Mobile for my web application and I'm using **ui-field-contain** and **ui-grid-a** as container divs for my content.

However, because of this all the elements contained within appear to be set to the full width of the screen and every element takes up an entire line on the page (even a span element).

I've been able to adjust width size using CSS, however, I would like to put some of these elements together and I'm at a loss in terms of how to accomplish that since it's not like I'm spacing them out with **br** tags.

Here's some of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

        <!--CSS Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css">

        <!--jQuery Mobile Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

        <!--jQuery Library-->
        <script src="includes/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <!--jQuery Mobile Library-->
        <script src="includes/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <!--jQuery Functions-->
        <script src="includes/js/functions.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>   
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>
                    Create Survey
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div id="main" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <div class="ui-field-contain">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a">
                            <label for="addQ" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Add Question</label>
                            <input type="button" value="Add Question" id="addQ" class="smallerBtns">

                            <!--Transportation Div-->
                            <div id="container">
                            </div>
                                <br>
                            <label for="submitSurvey" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Submit Survey</label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit Survey" id="submitSurvey">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createSurvey.php">Create Survey</a></li>
                        <li><a href="takeSurvey.php">Take Survey</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is some of the content I am appending via javascript into the container div:

```
//Question Type Visibility
$(document).bind("pageinit",function(){

    $("#container").empty();

    //Reset qCount
    qCount = 0;



    //jquery Add Question Event
    $(document).undelegate('#addQ', 'click').delegate('#addQ','click', function() {

        //Increment question counter
        qCount++;

        $('\
            <div id="newQ' + qCount + '">\
                <span id="num' + qCount + '" class="nums">' + qCount + '.</span>\
                \
                <!--Question Title-->\
                <label id="qTitleLabel' + qCount + '" for="qTitle" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Question Title:\
                </label>\
                <input type="text" name="qTitle' + qCount + '" id="qTitle' + qCount + '" placeholder="Question Title">\
                \
                <!--Question Type-->\
                <label id="qTypeLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQType' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Question Type:\
                </label>\
                <select name="addQType' + qCount + '" id="addQType' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '">\
                    <option selected disabled hidden value=\'\'>Pick a Type</option>\
                    <option value="smallTextDiv">Small Text</option>\
                    <option value="tORfDiv">True or False?</option>\
                    <option value="dropdownDiv">Dropdown</option>\
                    <option value="numDiv">Number</option>\
                    <option value="radDiv">Radio Buttons</option>\
                    <option value="largeTextDiv">Large Text</option>\
                    <option value="checkboxDiv">Checkboxes</option>\
                </select>\
                \
                <!--Small Text-->\
                <div id="smallTextDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                    <label id="addQSmallTextLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQSmallText' + qCount + '">\
                        Preview:\
                    </label>\
                    <input type="text" name="addQSmallText' + qCount + '" id="addQSmallText' + qCount + '">\
                </div>
          ').hide().appendTo("#container").fadeIn(1000).enhanceWithin();
    }) //end add question
}) //end document ready function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page should help you with grids...
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/grids/

If you need to have the form elements inline (side by side) you should also be able to use grids to complete the layout using nested grids

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-grid-a"><div>
   <div class="ui-grid-b"><div>
</div>
```

See this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/j5zbB/